# How can I add two bar buttons to a navigation bar? Getting an error

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to add two buttons to the left side of my navigation bar. One is put there through the storyboard. Here is what I've tried doing (what I found online)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        var resetButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: "Refresh", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "reset:")
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(resetButton, animated: false)
}
```

But I am getting an error that says: Cannot find an initializer for type: "UIBarButtonItem". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One problem you'll discover is that the single button you're trying to add in code will replace the single (storyboard) button that's currently on the left.  You want to pass an array of `barButtonItems` to `leftBarButtonItems:`

Comment: Okay, so assuming that I figure this out I will have to create the other button programmatically. Do you have any idea why this one doesn't want to work?

Comment: Did you want `barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, ...` or a custom button?

Comment: It is a custom button ineptly named "Refresh". It's a reset icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image parameter is expecting an image, not a string.

You probably want to use:

```
UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"Refresh.png"), style:.Plain, target:self, action:"reset")
```

You can add two buttons programmatically as follows:

```
let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"Refresh.png"), style:.Plain, target:self, action:"reset")
let other = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"Other.png"), style:.Plain, target:self, action:"other")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [refresh, other]
```

Comment: Wow. This was staring me in the face the whole time. Thank you so much!!